# Angular JS assistance required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Stack Over flow. I have this line of coding

```
  <div class="col-sm-9" ng-controller ="BlogController as blg" ng-repeat.start="detail in blg.details">
  <h4><small>RECENT POSTS</small></h4>
  <hr>
  <h2>I Love Food</h2>
  <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by Jane Dane, Sep 27, 2015.</h5>
  <h5><span class="label label-danger">Food</span> <span class="label label-primary">Ipsum</span></h5><br>
```

I want to use ng-repeat and have these titles and everything in a seperate js file. Can somebody help me with that. Thank you

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Please provide sample data that you want to iterate through, your javascript files, etc... Here is good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Welcome to SO!

Comment: I want to itterate title like the one at I love food and the date and Category of Food and Ipsum.
Like suppose there are 2 of these kinds in this case

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Comment: Yes the answer you gave was correct. It worked. I 'll be having a new problem though :3

Comment: In that case, check as correct answer :) Would be happy to help with new questions!

Comment: How do you do that :O

Comment: :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oadGdB3QzvkIUQicApl3?p=preview) is solution for you.

Angular app & controller:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('BlogController',function(){
this.details = [
                 {title: 'I Love Food',
                  author: 'Jane Dane',
                  date: 'Sep 27, 2015',
                  categories: [{name:'Food', class: ' label-danger'}, {name:'Ipsum', class: ' label-primary'}],
                  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
                 },
                 {title: 'I Love World',
                  author: 'Jane Dane',
                  date: 'Nov 12, 2015',
                  categories: [{name:'Nature', class: ' label-warning'}, {name:'Ipsum', class: ' label-primary'}],
                  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
                   }
                 ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="col-sm-9" ng-controller="BlogController as blg">
    <h4>
      <small>RECENT POSTS</small>
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <div  ng-repeat="detail in blg.details">
      <h2>{{detail.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{detail.content}}</p>
      <h5>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        Post by {{detail.author}}, {{detail.date}}.
      </h5>
      <h5>
        <span ng-repeat="category in detail.categories" class="label {{category.class}}">{{category.name}}</span>
      </h5>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Full solution in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oadGdB3QzvkIUQicApl3?p=preview).